# Android Install Location Auto Not Working

Tags: android, installation, sd-card, android-sdcard

I've set `installocation="auto"` in the manifest and on most devices this works.

Doesn't Work (No option to move to SD Card):
Razr Max HD (Android 4.0)
Samsung GS3 (4.0 and 4.1)
Samsung Note 2 (4.0)
Droid 4 (Android 4.0). This only said it would move to internal space however error'ed out saying there was no space (wrong).

Works:
Rooted, Incredible (4.1)
Samsung Note 1 (2.3.6)

Any ideas? It seems like +4.0 doesn't want to recognize the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some phones (such as the [Razr Max HD](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1991655) and [Galaxy S3](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1896924)) simply do not support moving apps to the SD card. Manufacturers unfortunately have the ability to remove this feature from their Android releases, and some use that power.